# datatable become slow while loading data from database using query

Tags: mysql, datatable

i have table in database with more than 10000 data.using ajax i am  getting value from database.but  table becoming too slow.i m using data Table for display data

Comment: Which language? What have you tried? Show code. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please give some idea about your code in your language.
But I would tell you something.

1)
If it is not necessary to fetch all data, than you can use pagination like first call of **1 to 100**, 2nd: **101 to 200** , So that you can get your response quickly.

e.g. **SELECT vFirstname from tbl_user LIMIT 1,100**

2)
If you want to get data than dont user '*' in select, Specify your field name.

e.g.
**SELECT vFirstname from tbl_user.**

Comment: i have to fecth all data..i am using Php,mysql,yii framework.

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue there are some solutions for slow query

- SELECT the required fields from table don't use (SELECT *)

for eg:-

> SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM table

- Use LIMIT in query don't fetch all 10000 records in single query

for eg :-

> SELECT field_1, field_2 FROM table LIMIT 0, 20

- Try to avoid loops after getting all records in your server side code

for eg :-

Dont use **for** loop, **foreach** loop or **while** loop after fetching data, pass the array of data directly as ajax response

Comment: @RituMS use pagination to display all records instead of showing 10000 records in single view check this tutorial [link] (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928) it might help you